# Perl script for Multi line text parsing from .txt

Tags: perl, delimiter, multiline

I have customer information on spending in categories.
Its in flat file as this with pipe delimiter.

```
Jane|groceries|$30.02
Victor|entertainment|$40.57
Cedric|fuel|$10.84
Jane|fuel|$20.93
Cedric|entertainment|$75.06
```

I need to generate output file stating amount spent by each customer

Comment: Did the formatting of this post show the way you intended or are these also line delimited? The reason I ask is because it will not be possible to parse this unless the character between each record are unique (unless you make the assumption that the first field in each record has no numerals).

Comment: Yes. The new customer is on the new line after the amount field

Answer (score 2):

```
my %sum_for;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my ($name, $item, $price) = split /[|]/;
    $price =~ s/^\$//;
    $sum_for{$name} += $price;
}

say "$_: \$$sum_for{$_}" for sort keys %sum_for;
```

Comment: I am trying to get a report listing their spending in each category using the code as                                      while(<FILE>) {
chomp; it doesnt work
 my ($name, $item, $price) = split /[|]/;
    $price =~ s/^\$//;
foreach $name ($item){
    $sum_for{$item} +=$price
}

Comment: to get it into category just do something like `$sum_for{$name}{$item} += $price;` this will produce hash of hash which you can sort first by name then category, for example Cedric, then fuel or entertainment

Answer (score 0):

Such things can be done with one liner in perl.

```
perl -F'\|' -lane '$F[2]=~s/\$//;$d->{$F[0]}+=$F[2];END{print"$_=>\$$d->{$_}" for keys %$d;}' your_file.txt
```

This first removes `$` from the price tag and then creates hash ref `Name => Amount` consecutively adding new `Amount` to the existing `Amount` value when the same `Name` appears. `END` tells perl to run what appears after this only once (after going through all the lines) since it's executing code with `-n` option.

Output:

```
Victor=>$40.57
Jane=>$50.95
Cedric=>$85.9
```

Options used:

- `-e` = may be used to enter one line of program (one liner mode)
- `-a` = turn on autosplit mode, puts values from split on @F array
- `-F'\|'` = set delimiter to |
- `-n` = causes perl to assume `while(<>){...}` loop around your program
- `-l` = enables automatic line-ending processing

More info on options used and possibilities: [Perlrun Doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)